# How to delete files in E drive

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to delete jpg files (e.g., IMG_0001.jpg , IMG_0002.jpg, etc.) from E drive. When I delete bmp files from C drive, it goes well.

I used this following code

```
File.Delete(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\4.Result\\image" + (index) + ".bmp");
```

However when I used this code, it went wrong,

```
if (index < 10)
{
    File.Delete(@"E:\DCIM\100PHOTO\IMG_000" + (index) + ".JPG");
}
else
{
    File.Delete(@"E:\DCIM\100PHOTO\IMG_00" + (index) + ".JPG");
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us what went wrong? And wat is the name(some example) of the image files in E Drive? Also check if the extension of the files are `jpeg`

Comment: The error is that there was no difference. it means files remain. I checked file format. It is the jpg file. thanks

Comment: Did you try to remove the `@`?

Comment: Yes. there was no @ in my previous code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using @ sign at the beginning of string don't use double '\\' just one '\' or delete @ sign and leave double '\\'
The another problem can be that the file doesn't exist on the disk.

Comment: first of all, thank you for replying.
I changed my code into  
File.Delete(@"E:\DCIM\100PHOTO\IMG_000" + (index) + ".JPG");
but jpg file is still remained.
I can't understand what you mean related to your second advise. Files exist on the E disk.

Comment: Can you show what value do you have in index variable? If files exist on this don't worry about second advice.

Comment: Is value same with file name?
If i am not mistaken, file name is IMG_0001.jpg to IMG_0052.jpg

Comment: in first code you have: `image" + (index) + ".bmp"`, in second `IMG_00" + (index) + ".JPG"`. Please check exactly what you have in variable index. The best will be to create varible `string filePath = @"E:\DCIM\100PHOTO\IMG_00" + (index) + ".JPG";` and check what is inside this variable.